# test for an argument being a 5 digit integer

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

I want to test whether or not an argument in my `bash` script is a 5 digit integer.

```
if [ "$1" == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]; then
    echo "first arg is 5 digits"
else
    echo "not 5 digits"
```

This does not work for me, is there an easier way to do this i.e. using the `expr` function?

Answer (score 4):

See `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` at `man bash`:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{5}$ ]]; then
    echo "first arg is 5 digits"
else
    echo "not 5 digits"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You must use double brackets when testing this kind of expression.

Comment: +1. single brackets do not understand `==` for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$1" in
  [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) echo "first arg is 5 digits" ;;
  *) echo "not 5 digits" ;;
esac
```